# Recieving an "invalid login" when attempting to login using php and mysql

Tags: php

I have viewed many sites compared various login scripts and can't find any solution. I put in the correct info and get an 'invalid login' also if i don't put anything in there i get an 'invalid login'. I could really use some help to troubleshoot. Here is the code

```
<?php 
  include_once ('dbc.php');

  $user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email']));

  if (isset($_POST['Submit'])=='Login')
  {
    $md5pass = md5($_POST['pwd']);
    $sql = "SELECT id,user_email FROM users WHERE 
              user_email = '$user_email' AND 
              user_pwd = '$md5pass' AND user_activated='1'"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ( $num = 0 ) 
    { 
      // A matching row was found - the user is authenticated. 
      session_start(); 
      list($user_id,$user_email) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
      // this sets variables in the session 
      $_SESSION['user']= $user_email;  

      if (isset($_GET['ret']) && !empty($_GET['ret']))
      {
        header("Location: $_GET[ret]");
      } else {
        header("Location: myaccount.php");
      }

      //echo "Logged in...";
      exit();
    } 

    header("Location: login.php?msg=Invalid Login");
    //echo "Error:";
    exit;       
  }
?>
```

Form Code----

```
<td bgcolor="#e5ecf9" class="mnubody"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">Your Email: 
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    </p>
    <p align="center"> Password: 
      <input name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd">
    </p>
    <p align="center"> 
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </p>
    <p align="center"><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="forgot.php">Forgot</a></p>
  </form></td>
```

Comment: Here is a suggestion: Simplify the code until it works, and then add functionality piece by piece.

Comment: I see your doing some type of email activation. Are you sure that part is working and setting the value to 1?

Comment: ohhhh, the happy 90s I miss those days. Are you learning PHP or this is real project. If it is real I suggest you look at an exisiting implementation and do not re-invent the wheel/**THEE most common feature in php OS systems.**

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])=='Login')
```

Will never run the code in that block.  isset returns true or false.

Try

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] =='Login')
```

That's why you always get redirected to the invalid login URL.  Beyond that, I didn't really check to see if there were any logical errors in the code.

Also, `$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email']));` won't give you the desired result either.

See [isset()](http://php.net/isset)

You also need to change `if ( $num = 0 )` to `if ( $num > 0 )`.  In either case, you need to use a double-equal `==` to compare values.  That would assign 0 to $num and execute the code in the body of that if statement.

Comment: How should this be handled? Also,   $user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email'])); won't give you the desired result either.

Comment: You can either suppress a warning in the event that a value isn't set like this: `$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['email']);` or redirect to an error page if it isn't set `if (!isset($_POST['email'])) { header('Location: error.php?msg=No%20email%20address%20provided'); exit; }`  Or just `$user_email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) : '';`

Answer (score 2):

if ( $num = 0 )

should be

if ( $num == 1 )

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

*Update:*

You should check for multiple rows that match. Throw exception/log anytime $num > 1. Such a check would help detect any database consistency issue that creeps in before your db is a complete disaster.

Comment: It should be `if ($num > 0)` or `if ($num == 1)`

Comment: @drew010 :P yeah I just wiped out what I noticed at first pass. (Updated)

Comment: if(1 == $num) is better practice :)